# Django: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a form, and pass on the values entered by the use into a database.

```
models.py

from django.db import models

class Evangelized(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile_no = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 128)
    twitter_url = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 128)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('U', 'Unisex/Parody'))
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    AREA_CHOICES = (('Govt', 'Govt'), ('Entertainment', 'Entertainment'), ('Automobile', 'Automobile'),
                        ('Careers', 'Careers'), ('Books', 'Books'), ('Family', 'Family'), ('Food', 'Food'),
                            ('Gaming', 'Gaming'), ('Beauty', 'Beauty'), ('Sports', 'Sports'), ('Events', 'Events'),
                                ('Business', 'Business'), ('Travel', 'Travel'), ('Health', 'Health'), ('Technology','Technology'))
    area_of_interest = models.CharField(choices = AREA_CHOICES, max_length = 128)
    other_area_of_interest = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length = 128)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))
    other_social_accounts = models.BooleanField(choices = BOOL_CHOICES, default = None)
    questions = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length = 1280)
    about_yourself = models.CharField(blank = False, max_length = 1280)
    referrer = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
```

forms.py

```
   from django import forms
from rango.models import Evangelized

class EvangelizedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    full_name = forms.CharField(help_text="Full Name")
    email = forms.CharField(help_text="Email ID")
    mobile_no = forms.CharField(help_text="Mobile number")
    twitter_url = forms.CharField(help_text="Twitter URL")
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
                 choices=Evangelized.GENDER_CHOICES, help_text="Gender")
    area_of_interest = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                                    choices=Evangelized.AREA_CHOICES, help_text="Areas of interest(Upto 3)")
    """def clean_area_of_interest(self):
        if len(self.cleaned_data['area_of_interest']) > 3:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Select no more than 3.')
        return self.cleaned_data['area_of_interest']"""
    other_area_of_interest = forms.CharField(help_text="Other area of interest")
    city = forms.CharField(help_text="City")
    other_social_accounts = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(),choices=Evangelized.BOOL_CHOICES, help_text="Do you have other social accounts?", max_length=128)
    questions = forms.CharField(help_text="Do you have any questions?")
    about_yourself = forms.CharField(help_text="Tell us about yourself")
    referrer = forms.CharField(help_text="I heard about this platform via:")

    class Meta:
        model = Evangelized
        fields = ('full_name', 'email', 'mobile_no', 'twitter_url', 'gender', 'area_of_interest', 'other_area_of_interest', 'city', 'other_social_accounts',
                    'questions', 'about_yourself', 'referrer')
```

views.py

```
def fillform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EvangelizedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit = True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            form.errors
    else:
        form = EvangelizedForm()

    return render(request, 'rango/fillform.html', {'form': form})
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /rango/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unique'
```

What seems to be wrong with my code? And what does this error signify?

EDIT:

I've modified the source code of my `forms.py` file, and also made a slight chance in the original title. Seems like the `choices` key in the parameters on my form fields is generating an error. However, the code is syntactically correct, right?

Comment: You shouldn't have spaces around the `=` in `keyword=value` arguments.

Comment: Eliminating spaces around the '=' didn't solve the problem. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I am not totally sure, but I think that the unique constraint on the fields is checked by the **model** validation, so that you don't need to specify unique=True in the **form** fields.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed what was generating that error. However, now the 'choices' keyword is throwing the same exception, even though the code is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Form fields like your `mobile_no` for example don't have a `unique` argument. Only model fields have that. You have to remove all `unique` arguments from your form model.

Comment: I have edited the question and the original post as well based on changing my code on your suggestions.

Comment: This time you used the wrong field type one `other_social_accounts` it should be a `ChoiceField`.

Comment: Some other fields as well, check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/ if the field type you are using have a `choices` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what was generating that error. The `choices` argument should have been defined inside the widget constructor in `forms.py` as follows:

```
from django import forms
from rango.models import Evangelized

class EvangelizedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    full_name = forms.CharField(help_text="Full Name")
    email = forms.CharField(help_text="Email ID")
    mobile_no = forms.CharField(help_text="Mobile number")
    twitter_url = forms.CharField(help_text="Twitter URL")
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(
                 choices=Evangelized.GENDER_CHOICES), help_text="Gender")
    area_of_interest = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
                                                    choices=Evangelized.AREA_CHOICES), help_text="Areas of interest(Upto 3)")
    """def clean_area_of_interest(self):
        if len(self.cleaned_data['area_of_interest']) > 3:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Select no more than 3.')
        return self.cleaned_data['area_of_interest']"""
    other_area_of_interest = forms.CharField(help_text="Other area of interest")
    city = forms.CharField(help_text="City")
    other_social_accounts = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=Evangelized.BOOL_CHOICES), help_text="Do you have other social accounts?", max_length=128)
    questions = forms.CharField(help_text="Do you have any questions?")
    about_yourself = forms.CharField(help_text="Tell us about yourself")
    referrer = forms.CharField(help_text="I heard about this platform via:")

    class Meta:
        model = Evangelized
        fields = ('full_name', 'email', 'mobile_no', 'twitter_url', 'gender', 'area_of_interest', 'other_area_of_interest', 'city', 'other_social_accounts',
                    'questions', 'about_yourself', 'referrer')
```

Comment: Alternatively, use ChoiceField rather than CharField.